# After The Fall, do humans have any kind of government?

Tags: politics, andromeda

After The Fall, it seems governments were split along racial lines - Nietzscheans, Than etc., but I don't recall any government system for Humans. Moreover, it seems Earth has been mostly abandoned, and is ruled by the Nietzscheans after The Fall, so it seems unlikely that Earth was the capital of any human government. Having said that, humans are seen serving in the New Commonwealth (even quite early in its life e.g. Max Lincoln in episode 3x02), so presumably they did have some form of organization able to sign the Commonwealth charter. Was there any mention or hint of a human government in existence after The Fall, or a hint of where its capital might have been?

Comment: Lots of planetary governments and quite a few small (and not so small) regional alliances, if memory serves

Comment: Agreed.  There was no central government for all humans, but there were many small regional alliances of human and human/non-human polities.